# Assign awk output to awk variable

Tags: unix, awk, gawk

How can I call an awk script from an awk script and assign the output of the first to a variable in the second?

I have an awk script that reads files each night, checks each line of data and writes to a new file. I need to add in some additional formatting to one of the fields.  I already have a standalone awk script that does the formatting so all I need to do is call this awk script for the appropriate fields and assign the value that is normally printed to a variable.

To put it in context, the following prints the required formatting to the screen (because that's what title_case.awk does), but I can’t use the value for further processing.

```
print old_name | ("/production/bin/title_case.awk")
```

so I need something like the following:

```
new_name = 'old_name | ("/production/bin/title_case.awk")
```

Thanks,

Ger

Comment: `new_name=$(command)`

Comment: Hi devnull.  I can't get that to work in awk.  For my example, what would I type? new_name=$(print old_name | ("/production/bin/title_case.awk"))  ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try using `getline` into a variable ( http://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#Getline_002fVariable_002fPipe )

```
("/production/bin/title_case.awk "old_name) | getline new_name
```

Comment: Thanks for the help Hakon.  I couldn’t get it to work exactly as you suggested because the variable old_name is not a file, however I managed to modify it slightly.  The following does what it should.

"echo "old_name" | /production/bin/title_case.awk" | getline new_name